# Why can't I assign Array in a int pointer in implicit declaration in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
    int *p={1,2,3,4};
    printf("%d",(*p+1));
    return 0;
```

While I run it, it terminates with signal 11.
And if I simply make an array and assign it to the pointer it works perfectly fine, what is the difference as {1,2,3,4} is also an array.

Comment: you code tries to create a pointer that is initialized with the value 1. On my machine it wont compile due to there being too many initializers. YOu code then dies because you dereference a pointer with a value of 1

Comment: *as {1,2,3,4} is also an array.* Is it? Could also be an initializer for a struct.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
int *p={1,2,3,4};
```

will not declare an array, because you are not declaring `p` as an array. You are declaring it as a single pointer. Also, you are assigning the value `1` to this pointer, which is illegal in ISO C. You cannot assign an integer to a pointer in ISO C. If you attempt to compile this in strict ISO C18 compliance mode, it will [fail to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/x9roo6h5W). It will also fail due to providing too many initializers.

If you want `p` to be an array of 4 `int` elements, then you can write it like this instead:

```
int p[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

If you want `p` to be a pointer that points to the first element, then you can write it like this instead:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *p = arr;
```

Due to [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471), the line

```
int *p = arr;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int *p = &arr[0];
```

Also, the line

```
printf("%d",(*p+1));
```

is probably not doing what you think it does. Due to the [rules on operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), this line is equivalent to the following:

```
printf("%d",(*p)+1);
```

However, you probably want the following instead:

```
printf("%d",*(p+1));
```

which is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d",p[1]);
```

Since you have defined your array contents in such a way that both are equivalent (both have the value `2`), you probably won't notice this bug. However, as soon as you change the array contents so that `p[1]` does not have the value `p[0] + 1`, this bug will become visible.

Here is an example of what your entire code should probably look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int *p = arr;
    printf( "%d\n", p[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

This program has the output `2`.

Note that in this program, the line

```
int *p = arr;
```

is not necessary, because you can simply write `arr[1]` instead of `p[1]`. You don't need the variable `p` at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no array in your code.

What you posted is equivalent to

```c
int *p = 1;
```

You could create an anonymous array as follows:

```c
int *p = ( int[] ){ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

This is the same thing as

```c
int anon[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *p = anon;
```

Comment: THANKS but if I simply assign string which is an array of char, why my code works fine?

Comment: @AnupAdhikari: because under most circumstances the array expression is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.  Arrays are weird and don't behave like other types, and what works for arrays doesn't work for anything else.

Comment: @ikegami I am taking about char *p

Comment: And also tell me how can I assign 2d arrays in array of pointers in implicit declaration

Comment: Re "*if I simply assign string which is an array of char, why my code works fine?*", Because then you do have an array. And when an array is treated as a pointer, it degenerates into a pointer to its first element. So that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Re "*How can I assign 2d arrays in array of pointers in implicit declaration*", Are you asking how to make the array in `int a[][4] = { { 1,2,3,4 }, { 5,6,7,8 } }; int (*p)[4] = a;` anonymous? If so, `int (*p)[4] = ( int [][4] ){ { 1,2,3,4 }, { 5,6,7,8 } };`

Comment: Yes but I want it to assign not in a pointer to whole array, instead in a array of pointer. Before you had cleared that typecasting we can assign a array in a pointer like:.                int *p = ( int[] ){ 1, 2, 3, 4 }; so as 1 pointer is assigned a array I want a array of pointers to get assigned 2d array.

Comment: But you said 2d-array, now you say array of pointers. This is going to far off-topic. If you have more questions, please post them as a Question.

Comment: And your edit says array of pointers of 2d arrays. Once you settle on a question, ask it as a Question. I'm tired of the moving goal post.

Comment: In any case, I've already shown how to create anonymous vars. Just remove the name from the declaration and put that in the parens, followed by the initializer.

Comment: I am sorry for that I am posting this as a clear question , Please give me few minutes.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int i;
 //int (*p)[]= (int [][3]) { {1,2,3},{10,20,30} };  
 
 int *p[]=  { (int [][3]) { {1,2,3},{10,20,30}  }  };
           
  
 
 for(int i=0;i<(2*3);i++)
 printf("%d ",*(*p+i));  
    


     return 0;
}    The actual problem is if I run code after uncommenting the initialization it gives no error and if I run like this it warns me like incompatible assignment but still provides correct output

Comment: How is the correct code working and the incorrect code warning a problem?